# How to configure istio-sidecar envoyproxy not to include x-envoy-peer-metadata in header data?

Tags: envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

The counterparty we connect to does not allow/handle that the x-envoy-peer-metadata is as big as what the istio-sidecar envoyproxy adds. (about 390 characters)

Is it possible to disable the x-envoy-peer-metadata and possible as well x-envoy-peer-metadata-id?

Searched for it and only found that it's recommended to disable it for security reason. but not found how.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found that you can remove headers like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: my-namespace
  name: my-namespace-google-remove-header
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.google.com
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: www.google.com
      headers:
        request:
          remove:
          - x-forwarded-proto
          - x-envoy-decorator-operation
          - x-envoy-peer-metadata-id
          - x-envoy-peer-metadata
          - x-envoy-attempt-count
```

Then in a ServiceEntry you say that [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) is an external entity.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: mesh-external-www-google-com
spec:
  hosts:
    - www.google.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
  resolution: NONE
```